# React-Native: Specify colors for neutral, positive and negative button in Android Alert

Tags: react-native

[Alert](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html) documentation on React-Native docs mentions below:

> Android
>   On Android at most three buttons can be specified. Android
>   has a concept of a neutral, negative and a positive button:
>
> If you specify one button, it will be the 'positive' one (such as
>   'OK') Two buttons mean 'negative', 'positive' (such as 'Cancel', 'OK')
>   Three buttons mean 'neutral', 'negative', 'positive' (such as 'Later',
>   'Cancel', 'OK')

Currently, the placement is done according to positive, negative and neutral button but they are all colored the same. Is there a way to specify the color as well? On iOS, we can specify a `style` property per button which colors the destructive button red.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not possible using Alert.

Android implementation as of 0.60 is this:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.60-stable/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/dialog/AlertFragment.java

You can see the only arguments taken into consideration is the text value, and uses default system theme to show the alert dialog.
So no way to customize the same.

You are better off making your own view and show https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{ text: 'cancel', onPress: noop, style: 'cancel' },`

Answer (score 0):

You can use libray like react-native-alert-pro to make altert more custom